# Prepopulate field collection programmatically

Tags: entities

I have a content type with field collection field (unlimited cardinality). Each collection has image field (required) and long text field.

How can I prepopulate node form with multiple collections? I need node creation form to have lets say 3 collection widgets (+1 blank) with already uploaded images.

How can I generate field collection widgets? I tried to manipulate with $form_state['values'] and $form_state['field'] in hook_field_attach_form - but have no effect.

Module code at [Github](https://github.com/molfar/field_collection_upload/tree/7.x-1.x)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the field type?  A screen shot of the manage fields might help too.

Comment: Ok screenshots explains why I was puzzled.  I had never heard of a field_collection_field. This is provided by a third party module [Field Collection](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection). I personally have never used this so I cannot provide an answer.

Comment: Can you give us more details on what you tried? Have you tried `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter` already? If you can't access the field collection, maybe you need to use an #after_build callback function to wait for the field collection array to be available for edit.

Comment: What have you tried? There are several pages that explain how to do this. Including [this](https://www.drupal.org/node/1477186). A Field Collection object is an entity so most that I have seen should work. If not post what you have tried here and we will try to figure it out.

Comment: I've tried both hook_form_alter and a #preprocess callback - can't get either of them to work. form.inc fails out on an unrelated element each time.

Comment: @Molfar What came out of this? Were you able to implement this?

Comment: Yes, I've made it with 2 manipulations with form_state. !https://www.evernote.com/shard/s21/sh/89246b45-3c83-497a-8e01-431503b81e17/0a994c8833d0b5ca04c2d4c62aadde73